# How can I list the current user and workspace in perforce?

Tags: perforce

What is the equivalent to typing `whoami` (Linux) in Perforce? I would like to programatically find the currently logged in user.

Can I also get the name of the current workspace, somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p4 info` gets you everything.

`p4 set P4USER` gets you the name of the user you've currently set (without connecting to the server to get any information about it -- you may or may not be logged in, and the user may or may not exist).

`p4 set P4CLIENT` is the same for the client name (doesn't validate that the client exists or anything like that).

`p4 login -s` gives you the current authentication status of the current user.

`p4 user -o` and `p4 client -o` give you more information about the current user and client.  You can use the `-Ztag` and `-F` global flags (see `p4 help usage` and `p4 help undoc`) to programmatically convert those forms into dictionaries and extract specific keys from them without needing to regex the text.  The various scripting APIs have this functionality baked in as well.

Answer (score 1):

Currently doing:

```
p4 info | grep 'User name'
p4 info | grep 'Client name'
```

Comment: Those are fine. Another way is to run `p4 set`.